# Getting LEGEND tags to wrap text properly

Tags: css, legend

Legend tags are always a nuisance as they don't adhere to a lot of CSS rules.

I'm trying to get the text within a LEGEND tag to wrap using the typical solution of wrapping the text in the LEGEND with a span and setting the width and display: block.

```
 <legend>
    <span style="border: 1px solid blue; width: 250px; display: block">
        This text should wrap if it gets longer than 250px in width
    </span>
 </legend>
```

I thought this used to work In Firefox, but does not appear to work anymore in 3.6. Sample:

http://jsbin.com/exeno/5

It still works in IE.

Has anyone found a fix for this or is it just a matter of forgoing LEGEND tags and go back to H# tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a requirement to use the `<span>` tag? I was able to get this working in Firefox 3.6.2 using a `<div>` tag and removing the `dislay: block;` element (as it is not needed in that case) as follows.

```
<legend>
    <div style="border: 1px solid blue; width: 250px;">
        This text should wrap if it gets longer than 250px in width
    </div>
 </legend>
```

It is at least an alternative unless you *must* use the `<span>` tag.

Comment: Woo! That does work. Thanks! In the end, though, we just gave up on the LEGEND. The other issue is that the legend doesn't obey width proportional to its container, while we can get it to wrap with a fixed pixel width using the div, we can't make that dynamic based on its parent so ended up just being too complicated. We switched to header tags.

Answer (score 2):

Was trying to get the same thing to work. In my scenario Firefox needed

```
legend {white-space:normal;}
```