# how to control the width of legend

Tags: html, css

```
<FIELDSET>
<LEGEND> Here my title goes.which is too long and need to be displayed in 2 lines like word-wrap. 
Line 2: Please suggest!</LEGEND>
Name: <INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE="20">
Email: <INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE="20">
</FIELDSET>
```

I tried max-width, word-wrap to both FieldSet and Legend as but Title is showing in a single line which incleases the box width and looks odd.

**Not browser specific problem

Comment: This code without any additional formatting does exactly that in Firefox – it displays the legend in two lines (or more) once the form width becomes too small to display it in one.

Comment: Is this a specific browser problem? As @CBroe says, the legend is wrapping automatically on Firefox. FYI, it wraps in Chrome and Safari too. Perhaps the issue is elsewhere? Please can you clarify the problem.

Comment: @CBroe I believe he wants it to wrap before reaching the width of the window. That said, `max-width` should work.

Comment: Perhaps the `white-space` has been set to `nowrap` somewhere? Set `white-space:normal;` to be sure.

Comment: This is apparently an IE-specific problem. IE does not divide the `legend` element. Some other browsers may have had the same problem in the past.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133571/how-can-i-make-legend-text-wrap

Comment: You say its not browser specific... What are you seeing that differs from your expected results? I'm able to have it automatically wrap OR force a wrap with a fixed width OR use a break without issue. Please help us to replicate your problem.

Comment: Have you tried limiting the width of your `form`?

Comment: OT: You should make your labels (Name:, Email:) ... `label` elements and associate each of them with their respective `input` via `for`/`id` attributes. Resource: [Using label elements to associate text labels with form controls (W3C WCAG 2.0)](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H44.html). And even better encapsulate both label and input in a paragraph, better semantics and a parent is often needed for layout purpose

Comment: @FelipeAls - doesn't help with the actual issue though.

Comment: @Moob "OT" stands for Off-Topic ;)

Comment: @FelipeAls Sorry. Now I feel stupid ;)

Comment: @Moob No problem! OT OP FYI ASAP FWIW SO SE... You're allowed not to know all of these acronyms/abbreviations ;)

Comment: @FelipeAls Guess I should have RTFM!

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the 'width' CSS attribute to what you want and the text will automatically wrap

```
legend{ outline: 1px solid red; width: 100px; }
```

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/YTJUA/

Comment: @nectar The demo in this answer is cleary working. Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try simply setting a width:

```
legend {
    width: 540px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pHtpL/

Answer (score 0):

For old IE you can put the content in a `span`. The span will wrap. For everything else `white-space:normal` should do the trick.

**Edit:** but you have to use a fixed width :(

```
legend {
    white-space: normal; 
}
legend span {
    display:block; width:100px;
}
```

**[This solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ktZBL/1/) is even better :)**

```
legend {
    white-space: normal; 
    display:table;
}
```

Comment: OMG @ IE... If you set the span to an absolute width [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/ktZBL/). I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I've updated my solution. `display:table` seems to sort >= IE8

Answer (score 0):

Just set this in your css:

```
fieldset {
    width:200px;
}
```

here you can set the width size as per your wish